# Autodesk Forge Data Manager Api rename a Item

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm tried to use this PATCH [Api](https://www.versti.eu/TranslateProxy/https/developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-PATCH/)  to rename item of "A360".
It returns 200 with DisplayName updated, but on myhub.autodesk360.com the item seems rendered with "Name" property of json object "Included".

this is the request body :

```
{
"jsonApi": {
    "version": "1.0"
},
"data": {
    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:tMqu2aQEToa3XsRmKzTTRg",
    "type": "items",
    "attributes": {
        "displayName": "new_item",
        "name" : "new_item"
    }
}
```

this is the response :

```
"data":    {
  "type": "items",
  "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:tMqu2aQEToa3XsRmKzTTRg",
  "attributes":       {
     "displayName": "new_item",
     "createTime": "2017-10-25T09:04:35.0000000Z",
     "createUserId": "QY23PAJ2YB4G",
     "createUserName": "bot@autodesk360.com",
     "lastModifiedTime": "2017-11-30T09:00:46.0000000Z",
     "lastModifiedUserId": "AYLNNU3UK324",
     "lastModifiedUserName": "Giuseppe Signorelli",
     "hidden": false,
     "extension":          {
        "type": "items:autodesk.core:File",
        "version": "1.0",
        "schema": {"href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/items:autodesk.core:File-1.0"},
        "data": {}
     }
  }
```

and object included :

```
"included": [   {
  "type": "versions",
  "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.tMqu2aQEToa3XsRmKzTTRg?version=2",
  "attributes":       {
     "name": "House Design.rvt",
     "displayName": "House Design.rvt",
     "createTime": "2017-11-09T16:50:30.0000000Z",
     "createUserId": "AYLNNU3UK324",
     "createUserName": "gsignorelli@tierratelematics.com",
     "lastModifiedTime": "2017-11-09T16:50:34.0000000Z",
     "lastModifiedUserId": "",
     "lastModifiedUserName": "",
     "versionNumber": 2,
     "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.revit",
     "storageSize": 12550144,
     "fileType": "rvt",
     "extension":          {
        "type": "versions:autodesk.core:File",
        "version": "1.0",
        "schema": {"href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.core:File-1.0"},
        "data": {}
     }
  }
```

I expected that on my client show same result that A360 shows.

Comment: Can you update your question with more details following the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to use **PATCH** API to rename the item name of BIM360 Docs, right? As far as I know, currently, **PATCH** APIs are only working on A360, they are not currently supported or encouraged for BIM 360 Docs. There might be a chance that allows for a folder rename, but it does not properly update the Docs database. So we do not recommend to use that APIs for BIM 360 Docs, and if you want to change a file name, I suggest you to upload a new version instead.

If you want to update the file name in A360, you should use PATCH API to a version, not an item. Here is what I tried, and the name of the file version is updated correctly:
[image]
PATCH API to update the name of the version, the trick thing is that you need to **URL encode the version id in the endpoint**, you can use any tools like https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to do that. This is different as the PATCH API to item.

Once you get the 200 status, your file name should be updated correctly in A360 as shown in the following picture:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for info, I updated the question to adding more details

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the file name was updated in A360 after you change the name of item by PAtCH API? I believe the name showed in A360 is version name, not item name. But it seems the PATCH API is not working to change the version information, I will check that more today.